# Reproject all layers in a spatialite file using ogr2ogr

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr, spatialite, loop

I would like to reproject all layers in a spatialite file from one srs to another srs.
Is there a way I can archieve this without parsing the layers names to a txt-file?
I know I can write all layernames to a txt file like this:

```
ogrinfo myfile.sqlite >layerlist.txt
```

But the content of the textfile has to be edited manually before I can use it to loop over the layernames as there is unneccessary content like this:

```
INFO: Open of `myfile.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.
1: layername1 any (Multi Line String)
2: layername2 any (Multi Polygon)
```

Is there a way I can loop over the layers without having to edit the layerlist manually?

Comment: Into which format?

Comment: @user30184 I want to do a coordinate transformation. perhaps my question was misleading. I edited my question to clarify what I want to do

Comment: If all layers have the same srs I would try `ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes -s_srs epsg:xxxx -t_srs epsg:yyyy output.sqlite input.sqlite`. Tell if it works or not, I haven't tried.

Comment: I thought I would have to specify each layer but indeed that works: ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes -s_srs epsg:31467 -t_srs epsg:25832 myoutfilee.sqlite myinfile.sqlite. GDAL/OGR rocks ;-)

Comment: It probably works then also with layers having different SRS by leaving out the -s_srs parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert all the layers from a datastore into another store with one ogr2ogr command. The target datastore must support multiple layers as well so for example SpatiaLite and other databases are OK while GeoJSON not. Also the ogr2ogr parameters must suit for all the layers.

This command copies all the layers from a SpatiaLite database into a new database and converts all geometries into the same coordinate system.

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes -t_srs epsg:yyyy output.sqlite input.sqlite
```